# Copying data to local storage from web services using Sencha Touch 2 + PhoneGap

Tags: html, cordova, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

Guys, I am a newbie to Sencha Touch 2 ...
I tried to calling a webservice using the below code in Store and displayed it in a list ..

```
Ext.define("NotesApp.store.Notes", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Store",
    config: {
        model: "NotesApp.model.Note",
        proxy: {
            type: 'jsonp',
            url: 'http://someURL/ServiceSencha.php',
            id: 'notes-app-store',
            extraParams: {
                type: 'fetch'
            },
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'Data'
            }
        },
        sorters: [{ property: 'dateCreated', direction: 'ASEC'}],
        grouper: {
            sortProperty: "dateCreated",
            direction: "ASEC",
            groupFn: function (record) {

                if (record && record.data.dateCreated) {
                    return record.data.dateCreated.toDateString();
                } else {
                    return '';
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The above code worked fine ..

So now i am trying to copy the entire data from the webservice and store it locally in HTML5 localStorage ..

Please help me guys how to do this ...